# How to add arbitrary inline images in Rails Mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-5, slim

I'm working on a Rails app that sends emails with arbitrary HTML content. In the mailer, we have:

```
class YeetMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email(html)
    
    # custom method that returns string[] where each string is an image src attribute
    @images = get_images_for_yeet_email(html)

    # add image attachments / Content-ID headers
    @images.map { |i|
      attachments.inline[i] = URI.open(i).read
    }

    # pass the html to the view
    @html = html
  end
end
```

Then in the view `yeet_mailer/welcome_email.slim`:

```
= @html
```

All of the guides I've seen (e.g. [this Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#making-inline-attachments)) suggest one should use `<%= image_tag attachments['image_name.jpg'].url %>` to get the images with cid content to render in the email, but I haven't yet figured out how to do so in the case of an arbitrary number of images.

I thought I could do:

```
@images.map { |i|
  attachments.inline[i] = URI.open(i).read
  html = html.sub(i, attachments.inline[i])
}
```

To make the replacements, but this throws `no implicit conversion of Mail::Part into String`. I added a `byebug` line to get into a debugger inside the `welcome_email` method and `puts(attachments.first)` gave some insight ([here's the output](https://gist.github.com/duhaime/0001fa6fc7d511d50a4c90ff3800dde1)), so I'm getting closer...

Anyone know how I should proceed? Any pointers would be very helpful!

Comment: I think the problem come from here : `@images.map { |i|  attachments.inline[i] = URI.open(i).read  }` where you use the url instead of the name. Maybe make an array with name and url and display the name of the file `.inline["my-file.png"]` and call the same in the view (I am not inlining anymore so I checked some old code so can't guarantee though)

Comment: I'm afraid you may have misunderstood my question--I believe the images are being attached to the email headers correctly; I'm really just asking how to incorporate the `img_tag` helper into the full fledged HTML string I already have. Like how can I get that `<%= img_tag ... %>` logic into the html, because a standard `sub` call in the mailer action function throws...

Comment: ok I see. What I understand is that you want to add images as attachments and also display them. I think you could add your own meta tags in the original HTML like `<<<hereimages>>>`and then replace this custom tag by `@images.map {|i| "<img src=#{i} >"}.join` Don't actually include the attachments declaration inside this bit. Keep the `attachments.inline[i]= etc..` in the mailer

Comment: my bad probably you have to use attachment url instead of plain url : `@images.map {|i| "<img src=#{attachments[i].url} >"}.join` not too sure here. Let me know now if it leads to something. I may try a few things on real code if you still have errors.

Comment: @Maxence would you mind converting some of these comments into an answer and then removing the comments? SO gets upset about long comment threads on questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can:

```
   @images.each_with_index { |i, idx|
      attachments.inline[i] = URI.open(i).read
      cid = attachments[idx].header.find { |h| h.name == 'Content-ID' }.field.value
      html = html.sub(i, "cid:#{cid}")
   }
```